# Why is it wrong to have cacheable https response?

Tags: security, http-headers

So, recently I ran a security scan on a webpage.  In one suggestion, it said "Caching Https Response" for image/js/font files, which seems counterintuitive.  And this suggestion seems to be the consensus among different security products.

- https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00700100_cacheable-https-response
- https://www.valencynetworks.com/kb/cacheable-https-response.html
- https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7009057

So, why does caching static files matter in HTTP or HTTPS mode?  I thought modern practice is make everything HTTPS to avoid tampering, and browser-caching to avoid extra download.

Lastly, if we WANT to cache static content in HTTPS mode, what is the correct thing to do?  Add extra logic to make it call HTTP instead?  That seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a warning, designed to protect people from unknowingly allowing private responses to be cached. Those descriptions all say some variation of "*If* sensitive information is stored in the cache...". Note the "If".

If you are knowingly allowing the content to be cached, then there's no problem. I assume the tool is showing this only on secure requests because of a presumption that such information might be sensitive.

Comment: Make sense.  So, I don't supposed there is a "more correct" way to have caching in HTTPS then?

Comment: @kainr2: There's not a more correct way. It's possible that a tool might only complain about the absence of headers (as opposed to including specific headers allowing caching), since that's more likely to be unintentional. But that would depend on the tool, and I personally wouldn't change my cache behavior just to eliminate a false positive in a tool.